# Angular 6 subjects vs behavior subject

Tags: angular, typescript

i have worked on a application which using behavior subject  for data transfer for all the component , is it really a good practice using observable concept.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(123);

// two new subscribers will get initial value => output: 123, 123
subject.subscribe(console.log);
subject.subscribe(console.log);

// two subscribers will get new value => output: 456, 456
subject.next(456);

// new subscriber will get latest value (456) => output: 456
subject.subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Subject**: A Subject observable is used to immediately notify subscribers of updated values emitted by it. It does not keep track of old values, i.e. if a Subject observable first emitted a value and was then later subscribed to, then the subscriber will not get get that value. You can think of a Subject like a live update / feed. Old values emitted from the time of its creation up to its subscription are not preserved; only values emitted after its subscription can be captured.

**BehaviorSubject**: A BehaviorSubject behaves like a normal Subject Observable but it has an extra feature, i.e. it preserves the last emitted value. That means if a value was emitted earlier from a BehaviorSubject and if a subscription was added after the value was emitted, then the subscription will give the last value that was emitted. The BehaviorSubject last value can be also retrieved using .value on the BehaviorSubject